# Sub pages not working after enable HTTPS?

Tags: php, yii2, apache2

I enabled HTTPS for my site and it works fine at homepage mysite.com(https).

But in sub page it not work, mysite.com/subpage(https).

> The requested URL /subpage was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at www.subpage.com Port 443

My site was writen by Yii2.

I had dump index.php file and the result of subpage is not go into index.php.

Thanks for any help.
Vien.

Comment: update your question and add  the  related  code ..

Comment: Sorry. This is my fault. I forget some config in default-ssl.conf


   `<Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>`

Now. It works fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forget some config in defau-ssl.conf.

`<Directory /var/www/html> 
    Options Indexes 
    FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
    AllowOverride All Order allow,deny allow from all 
</Directory>`

Now. It works fine :)